# After upgrading to ubuntu 15.04 urfkilld use 100% cpu

Tags: dell, 15.04, xps

I've upgraded my DELL XPS 13 equipped with Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 then to 15.04 yesterday.

Today I noticed that **urfkilld** process consumes 100% the CPU, I tried to kill it, but re-run again.

Answer (score 1):

`man urfkilld`

```
DESCRIPTION
       urfkilld provides the org.freedesktop.URfkill service on the system
       message bus. Users or administrators should never need to start this
       daemon as it will be automatically started by dbus-daemon(1) whenever
       an application calls into the org.freedesktop.URfkill service.
```

The dbus-daemon whenever an application calls into the org.freedesktop.URfkill service, though you can't just kill it.

Now back to your problem,this is a bug described here:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/urfkill/+bug/1385641.

[**A workaround, appears in comment 16**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/urfkill/+bug/1385641/comments/16)

I can confirm that adding the following script as /etc/pm/sleep.d/urfkill and giving it exec permissions solved the problem for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# urfkilld restart (LP#1385641)

[ -f /etc/init/urfkill.conf ] || exit 0

/usr/sbin/service urfkill restart
```

Comment: sorry, but the solution above worked temporary. The process resumes its execution now. I think it has a relation with network communication.

Comment: Read the comments in the bug link above, there is no static solution, it's a bug, try to upgrade the package or install it from source

Comment: I tried  sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade urfkill, no update is available !

Comment: did you read the comments here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/urfkill/+bug/1385641?

Comment: Read them and try to install from source, this may solve your problem

Comment: available bug fixes are not considering Ubuntu 15.04.