# restart urfkill after resume from suspend

Tags: suspend, cpu-load

How can I restart a the process urfkill (which consume 100% of CPU), each time the system resume from suspend. I've applied solution provided here [After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04 urfkilld use 100% cpu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628355/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-15-04-urfkilld-use-100-cpu/628360#628360), however, it works only when system resume from hibernate or when it is restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by changing  /etc/pm/sleep.d/urfkill file permissions from root to current user.